# How do I get a call's id in Voximplant's scenario?

Tags: voximplant

I am trying to setup my Voximplant call scenario, and i need callId, how can i get it? I've searched the documentation, but failed to found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method:
https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/call#id

This method returns the call's ID.